# "FreeImage is not set up correctly. Please ensure FreeImage is set up correctly" error when trying to verify cudnn installation

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I followed the steps in:

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html to set up cudnn.

Everything seems to be working fine but when I executed "make clean && make", I got the warning shown in the title and no mnistCUDNN was created.

Somebody suggested setting the CUDA_PATH using: 
export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local.cuda-9.0

but it does not work. I also tried:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.0/ /usr/local/cuda-9.0

but same issue. Then, I tried:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.0/ /usr/local/cuda

Again, same issue.

I also executed the following line as somebody mentioned:

cat /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cudnn_v7.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2

but I still get:

make clean && make
rm -rf *o
rm -rf mnistCUDNN
/usr/bin/ld: -lcublas cannot be found
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

> > > WARNING - FreeImage is not set up correctly. Please ensure FreeImage is set up correctly. <<<
> > >       :
> > >       :
> > >       :

Doing "sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7*.deb" and repeat Sec 2.4 Verifying cuDNN is installed resulted in the same error.

Executing: nvcc --version

leds to "Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit"

Not sure if I need to do that.

Could you please help to resolve the issue?

Also, I am concerned that I might set the wrong path and make the wrong symbolic links. Please let me know how to undo the above three lines of command that don't work.

Answer (score 17):

Installing the library fixed this for me

```
sudo apt-get install libfreeimage3 libfreeimage-dev
```

I found the solution here...

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1043665/?offset=3#5302165

Regarding the second part of your question for nvcc...

I'm sure you added the PATH correctly per the install guide, but if you reboot then the PATH will be reset. You'll need to add it to ~./bashrc or one of the many other options described here:

https://stackabuse.com/how-to-permanently-set-path-in-linux/
"How to Permanently Set $PATH in Linux" By  Tendai Mutunhire